# How do you tell if a wave is reflected or refracted at an interface?

Tags: waves, reflection, refraction

My physics textbook says that a wave traveling through medium $1$ will enter medium  $2$ if medium $1$ has a higher index of refraction. Otherwise, the wave will be reflected. This makes absolutely no sense to me, since this would mean all sunlight traveling through the vacuum of space would just bounce off Earth's atmosphere since air has a higher index of refraction than a vacuum.

There has to be something else that goes on for determining if a wave will be reflected or refracted at an interface, but my textbook doesn't elaborate any further past the statement already mentioned. Can someone tell me what the actual criteria is?

**Edit**

Nevermind, I misread the passage. Turns out the terms "reflect" and "invert" are not nearly as interchangeable as I thought they were.

Comment: Where you read that, were they talking about a wave at normal incidence to the 2nd medium, or did they specify an angle of incidence?

Comment: For a situation where there is complete reflection and no transmission, see [total internal reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection).

Comment: Which textbook is this, out of curiosity?

Comment: Mazur, to be fair I'm pretty sure the book is actually trying to say that waves are partially reflected and partially reflected, but the explanation for the thin film interference section is very bad, and the only diagram it has is incredibly misleading.

Comment: @SheepSoniX Can you provide a reference to exactly where Mazur makes this claim?

Comment: You may want to read up on the Fresnel equations in fir example Wikipedia.

Comment: A thin film is a special case, transmission is not  just dependent on  he index of refraction but also heavily depends on the thin film thickness.

Comment: @J.Murray I see now that it was a misunderstanding that was my own fault. His claim was was that a wave will be ***inverted***  if it encounters a medium with a higher index of refraction, not reflected. I was confused because figure 34.37 has an arrow pointing to a ray that is reflecting as well as inverting. I didn't realize there was a significant difference between the terms "reflecting" and "inverting".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good that it makes absolutely no sense to you, because that is absolutely wrong, and if your book truly says that then it should be cast into the nearest volcano as soon as possible.

In general, light incident upon an interface will be neither completely reflected nor completely transmitted.  The [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) are used to determine the reflection and transmission coefficients $R$ and $T$, which tell you what fraction of the incident light is reflected and transmitted, respectively.

Unfortunately, the Fresnel equations are rather complicated, and depend both on the refractive indices of the two media as well as the [polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_(waves)#s_and_p) of the incoming wave.  If we make a few simplifying assumptions for normal materials and visible light, we have the following:

For $p$-polarized waves, in which the electric field oscillates in the same plane as the interface, the reflection coefficient is

$$R_p = \left|\frac{n_1\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{n_1}{n_2}\sin(\theta_i)\right)^2}-n_2\cos(\theta_i)}{n_1 \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{n_1}{n_2}\sin(\theta_i)\right)^2}+n_2\cos(\theta_i)}\right|$$

For $s$-polarized waves, in which the electric field oscillates in the direction normal to the interface, the reflection coefficient is

$$R_s = \left|\frac{n_1\cos(\theta_i) - n_2\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{n_1}{n_2}\sin(\theta_i)\right)^2}}{n_1\cos(\theta_i) +  n_2\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{n_1}{n_2}\sin(\theta_i)\right)^2}}\right|$$

In both cases, the amount of light (specifically, the intensity of the beam as a fraction of the incident intensity) transmitted is $T_{s/p} = 1-R_{s/p}$.